# Giving a 4 Digit Random Code to all users within Database

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I would like to update my users database with a 4 digit random number.

I seem to have got stuck, on the bit for the loop, so that it will give a different random number to each user in the database. So far i have this.

```
$newpincode = array(sprintf("%04d",mt_rand(0,9999)));

$users_sql = "SELECT * FROM wifi_users";
$result_users = mysql_query($users_sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_users)){

foreach ($newpincode as $pin) {

    $sql = "UPDATE wifi_users SET `pincode` = '" . $pin . "' WHERE id = '" . $row['id'] . "'";
    $resultCount = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Aside from using the deprecated MySQL extension, you're trying to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` after an `UPDATE` statement. What's `$count` supposed to store? You're overwriting it on each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just run a single query:

```
UPDATE wifi_users SET `pincode` = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 10000), 4, '0')
```

Note this doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but then again neither does your current code.  4 digits doesn't give you enough values to provide uniqueness anyways if you plan on having more than 10000 users.

Comment: Would that solution not sometimes return values that are less than 4 characters in length? Maybe `ROUND((RAND() * (9999-1000))+1000)` would be better.

Comment: Exactly the very simple thing i required, that saved me coding another script, wonderful. Thankyou

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes you are correct.  I updated the example to simply left pad with zeroes to 4 characters in length.  This would allow for values like `0001`, `0010`, `0100` that wouldn't be available if you simply returned a range between 1000-9999.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a unique random number for each user check this out: [How to Generate Random number without repeat in database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680025/how-to-generate-random-number-without-repeat-in-database-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newpincode = rand(0, 9).rand(0, 9).rand(0, 9).rand(0, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the same pin code is given to all users.

Also, your inner loop would theoretically update the same record multiple times, although in this case that only happens once per record.

To issue a new pin code for each record, you have to move the pin code generation *inside* the outer loop and remove the inner loop.

As an aside, consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements.