# rand() number Where its != specific number

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a random number using rand() Where the number != to ( 516 for instance )

for instance if I have number "5" in the database and I want to insert a random number != 5.

Comment: Wouldn't be super efficient, but you could just generate a number in an infinite loop, and only break out of it if the generated number != your excluded number. I can't think of a way to straight generate a random number, excluding a certain number.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain why the number needs to be 'random'.

Comment: I would think a do/while statement would work out well here. Need more example code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate its not gonna work because I have a list of numbers in the database and I want to generate a number != to all of them.

Comment: does it have to be random? why not just get the max value from the database and add 1

Comment: @p.s.w.g it has to be random because I am creating a secure login system based on cookies.

Comment: @Twisty loop statements wont work since I am looking for one number != to all numbers in the database.

Comment: I would advice using [uuid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/1338292) instead.

Comment: there are better ways to generate unique values than to use rand() over and over.

Comment: @pala_ it has to be random because I am creating a secure login system based on cookies, so the number has to be unpredictable.

Comment: If the intent is to generate secure (i.e. cryptographically secure) random numbers, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182584/secure-random-number-generation-in-php).

Comment: If you want to pull a random number and make sure it isn't in your DB already this might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680025/how-to-generate-random-number-without-repeat-in-database-using-php

Answer (score 2):

One solution...

```
$disallow = 5;
$random_value = $disallow;
while($random_value == $disallow) {
    $random_value = rand();
} 
echo $random_value;
```

Documentation on rand, http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php.

Comment: Did you know something about [tag:python] ? I have not never think like your answer else I have read some tutorials about Python!

Comment: Nope, I haven't dabbled into the python world much.

Answer (score 1):

this one will exclude all values given in an array.

```
$excluded_nums = array( .... );
$val = null;
do {
  $val = rand();
} while (in_array($val, $excluded_nums));
```

but you may be interested in exploring another method, perhaps [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a secure login system based on cookies, so the number has to be unpredictable.

Instead of generating numbers, it's recommended to generate an opaque identifier such as [UUID v4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) that's meant to be unpredictable (provided a proper entropy source is used); an example identifier:

```
de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014
```

I've created a function to generate this identifier in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/1338292).

> I have a list of numbers in the database and I want to generate a number != to all of them

The approach I would recommend is to add a [UNIQUE constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) on the identifier and write a loop that generates a new identifier and attempts to insert it; it ends when the insertion doesn't cause a constraint error; to put the odds in perspective, you're more likely to get hit by a meteorite than hitting a duplicate value.

Answer (score -1):

Use arrays and rand:

```
$ran_begin = array(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9);//not contain 5 and 0
$ran = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$random_value = '';
$k = array_rand($ran_begin);
$v = $array[$k];
$random_value = $random_value.$v;

$k = array_rand($ran);
$v = $array[$k];
$random_value = $random_value.$v;


$k = array_rand($ran);
$v = $array[$k];
$random_value = $random_value.$v;
```

..............................

Comment: well thats inefficent