# Automatically generating 6 digit unique number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `'users'` with the follwing columns

- id
- email
- password
- pin

  I want the '**pin**' to be auto-filled with a unique *6 digit number* every time a new record is added. It would be of a great help if anyone could suggest a good approach for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Generate Random number without repeat in database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680025/how-to-generate-random-number-without-repeat-in-database-using-php)

Comment: What if you have a million ids?

Answer (score 1):

Define the PIN column as

```
pin MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Why `MEDIUMINT`? That's needlessly specific.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **zerofill** option for your int field. the Mysql fills it for your.

```
CREATE TABLE `int6` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**sample**

```
 MariaDB [l]> drop table int6;
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]> CREATE TABLE `int6` (
    ->   `id` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [l]> insert into int6 VALUES (1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> select * from int6;
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 000001 |
| 000002 |
| 000003 |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
```