# generate unique random number in mongoose db without repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, mongoose

i want to generate a random number which should not be repeated based on the numbers from my mongoose db, i don't wanna use this for a unique number:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000)
```

i found this answer which is in php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680025/how-to-generate-random-number-without-repeat-in-database-using-php)

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num
FROM numbers_mst 
WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT my_number FROM numbers_mst)
LIMIT 1
```

how can i do that but in mongoose?

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100/2380113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate your random number and check that it is not already stored:

```
function getNumber(callback){
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000);
    YourModel.findOne({'number': n}, function(err, result){
        if (err) callback(err);
        else if (result) return getNumber(callback);
        else callback(null, n);
    });
}

getNumber(function(error, number){
    console.log(number);
});
```

If you think this process could be called more than once in parallel, you should do some additional checks:

```
var alreadyRuning = false;
function getNumber(callback){
    if (alreadyRuning) return setTimeout(function(){
        getNumber(callback);
    }, 10);

    alreadyRuning = true;

    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000);
    YourModel.findOne({'number': n}, function(err, result){
        if (err) callback(err);
        else {
            alreadyRuning = false;
            if (result) return getNumber(callback);
            else callback(null, n);
        }
    });
}

getNumber(function(error, number){
    console.log(number);
    //...

    YourModel.insert({'number': n}, function(err, result){
        if (!err) alreadyRuning = false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do this on the database, like your SQL-example.
There is a ticket for adding a $rand operator to the aggregation pipeline, but that ticket is still unresolved:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30405

Still, you could create a database-function (which can have a bad performance) and store it on the server: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

That's not really a mongoose solution, though.